# Using a Ternary Operator to a "0" within the statement

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I'm trying to format a time using a variable input. If a user enter an hour as 1 - 9 the out put would include a "0", and the same for minutes. So far if a user enters 1 hour 3 minutes the output reads 1:3 instead of 01:03.

How do I get the extra 0 in front of numbers less than 10.

Here's the code.....

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FormatTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int MinutesInput;
        int HoursInput;
        int Hours;
        int Minutes;

        {
            System.out.println("Enter hours between 1 and 24");
            Hours = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter minutes between 1 and 59");
            Minutes = input.nextInt();

            {
                **//THIS NEXT LINE IS THE PROBLEM**
                HoursInput = Hours < 10 ? "0" + Hours : Hours;
                System.out.print(HoursInput + ":");
            }
            {
                **//THIS NEXT LINE IS THE PROBLEM**
                MinutesInput = (Minutes < 10) ? "0" + Minutes : (Minutes); 
                System.out.print(MinutesInput);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing `int` and `String` types:

```
int HoursInput;
//...
HoursInput = Hours < 10 ? "0" + Hours : Hours;
```

There are two problems with your code: you are trying to store string `"07"` (or similar) in an `int`. Secondly even if it was possible, `07` is equivalent to `7` as far as integer types are concerned (well, leading `0` has a special octal meaning, but that's not the point).

Try this instead:

```
String hoursInput;
//...
hoursInput = Hours < 10 ? "0" + Hours : "" + Hours;
```

Comment: I used this and it worked thanks a lot your ace. I just had to change the HoursInput and MinutesInput values to a string. Simple

Answer (score 3):

> How do I get the extra 0 in front of numbers less than 10.

You don't, while the target variable is of type `int`. An `int` is just a number, not a string - whereas `"0" + Hours` is a string.

`int` values don't contain any sort of string representation - the number sixteen is just as much "0x10" or "0b10000" as it is "16"... or even "00016" if your decimal representation allows much digits. ("00016" may be mis-interpreted as fourteen, however, if it's parsed as an octal string...)

Use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to convert numbers into strings in your desired format, or [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), or possibly just [`PrintStream.printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) if you want to write it straight to the console.

I'd also *strongly* recommend that you use `camelCase` for your local variables, and only declare them when you first need them.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same as `0020`, not `00016`?  Since you're describing how to write 16 in hex and binary, but `00016` won't actually give you the number sixteen...

Comment: @LouisWasserman: It depends on whether or not you're assuming some horrible octal-parsing format. Will edit to clarify.

Comment: as I'm only learning, I'm told by my tutor the user will input a valid time.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should be using

```
System.out.printf("%02d:%02d%n", Hours, Minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use String variables or use format method (similar to sprintf from c) from String class.

```
String time = String.format("%02d:%02d", hours, minutes );
```